# `ZQ` does not work on vi version installed on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, vi

When I open a file with the default `vi` on FreeBSD and press the buttons `ZQ` (close without saving) it tells me `Usage: ZZ`.
But `ZZ` saves any modifications and I don't want that.
`:q!` works, though.

```
:version
Version 2.2.0 (2020-08-01) The CSRG, University of California, Berkeley
```

What is the alias for `ZQ` in the `vi` installed on FreeBSD?

Comment: `ZQ` is a vim thing, not a vi thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvi` supports no such feature. One way would be to fork or otherwise patch in support for `ZQ` into

https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/contrib/nvi/vi/v_cmd.c#n344

and other files via a new `v_zexit_no_really` command, modeled after `v_zexit` but skipping the "fail if something has been modified" checks.

Another way would be something like

```
map ZQ :q!^V^M
```

set in `~/.exrc` where the caret bits are <kbd>CONTROL+V</kbd> and <kbd>CONTROL+RETURN</kbd>.

Or, you could install `vim` or `neovim` from the ports and use that.